# How to create fragments in Android studios from existing activities

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I have searched online and still cant manage to find any help of how to create fragments from existing activities. for example I have a dashboard activity and a menu activity which I would like to create fragments with so that it displays both of the pages on tablets as one screen.

I also want to create from fragments from menu pages to other pages as well. for example I want to display menu page on one side and the categories on the other side once clicked on one of the activities.

I can only find list view and detail examples. Do I need to create fragments for each activity. Please advise.

Menu Actvity. Java

```
public class MenuActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    private Toolbar toolbar;

    ImageButton museummenubtn;
    ImageButton theatremenubtn;
    ImageButton fooddrinkmenubtn;
    ImageButton leisuremenubtn;
    ImageButton shoppingmenubtn;
    ImageButton historicalmenubtn;
    ImageButton parkmenubtn;
    ImageButton familyfunmenubtn;
    ImageButton travelinformenubtn;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        ImageButton museummenubtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.museum_icon);
        museummenubtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MuseumActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                finish();
            }

        });

        ImageButton theatremenubtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.theatre_icon);
        theatremenubtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), TheatreActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                finish();
            }

        });

        ImageButton fooddrinkmenubtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.fooddrink_icon);
        fooddrinkmenubtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), FoodAndDrinksActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                finish();
            }

        });

        ImageButton leisuremenubtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.leisure_icon);
        leisuremenubtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), LeisureActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                finish();
            }

        });

        ImageButton shoppingmenubtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.shopping_icon);
        shoppingmenubtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ShoppingActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                finish();
            }

        });

        ImageButton historicalmenubtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.histroy_icon);
        historicalmenubtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), HistoricalActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                finish();
            }

        });

        ImageButton parkmenubtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.park_icon);
        parkmenubtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ParksActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                finish();
            }

        });

        ImageButton familyfunmenubtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.familyfun_icon);
        familyfunmenubtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), FamilyFunActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                finish();
            }

        });

        ImageButton travelinformenubtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.travelinfor_icon);
        travelinformenubtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), TravelInformationActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                finish();
            }

        });


        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_user) {
            Intent intent= new Intent(this,DashboardActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        int id1 = item.getItemId();

        if (id1 == R.id.action_setting) {
            Intent intent= new Intent(this,DashboardActivity.class);// Settings Class once it is created.
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

activitymenu.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        ></include>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/museum_icon"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:src="@drawable/museumicon"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/theatre_icon"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:src="@drawable/theatreicon"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/museum_icon"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/museum_icon"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/fooddrink_icon"
            android:src="@drawable/foodicon"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/theatre_icon"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/theatre_icon"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/leisure_icon"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/leisureicon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/shopping_icon"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/shoppingicon"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/leisure_icon"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/leisure_icon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/histroy_icon"
            android:src="@drawable/historicalicon"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/shopping_icon"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/shopping_icon" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/park_icon"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/parkicon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/familyfun_icon"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/familyfunicon"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/park_icon"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/park_icon" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/travelinfor_icon"
            android:src="@drawable/travelicon"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/familyfun_icon"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/familyfun_icon" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

MuseumActvity.XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar"
    ></include>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="260dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/musehead"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/museumhead"
        android:background="#ffffff" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="260dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4" >

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/gallerieshead"
        android:background="#ffffff" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to create a fragment from these two activities, so that it fits tablet screen size.

Comment: Structurally (code-wise), you just inflate a view instead of using setContentView and have onCreateView as well as onCreate. Other than that, there aren't many other changes. What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: I am having problems with creating fragments, Do I need to create one fragment per activity. Is this correct?. I want my application to support tablets as well as mobile phones.

Comment: "I am having problems with x" is not very descriptive... Yes, you need to create a Fragment for each individual *layout*, which are currently displayed using single activities. But you will also need an Activity class that will show those Fragment(s). If you add the code for the activity you are trying to convert, a more detailed answer can be given

Comment: I have updated my question with code. for example I have a menu activity and then I have various different activities such as museum, theaters, food & drink and etc. I want to create fragments so that it fits tablet sizes my displaying both a and B together on one view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need separate fragments for each activity. You can do it like this:
Make your menu activity a fragment so then you will have menu fragment then you can load menu in your other activities from a fragment container.

Like wise you will be able to hold your menu and dashboard in one  activity any where in the app.

Comment: Max do you have a tutorial which I can follow or any help appreciated?

Comment: This  tutorial will help you http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: Thanks Max, your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to create fragments for each activity, **you can use more than one fragment for activity** AS in your question for example if you want to display menu page on one side and the categories on the other side once clicked on one of the activities **:-** For this you can create two fragment and use both in your single activity as well as you can use one fragment in many activies if you have such requirements.

Checkout some good tutorial on Fragment

[Android - Fragments](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm) AND [Official documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/basics/fragments/creating.html)

you will come to know easily.

Comment: Amit Vaghela I am still struggling can you please give me an example which is more like mine, as all the fragments are regarding listview and detail view. Mine is more like menuview with all image buttons and then imageview on the other page as well. Please advise?

Comment: check this examples - http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-action-items-from-within-fragments/ and http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/Demonstrateshowfragmentscanparticipateintheoptionsmenu.htm @J.Doe

Comment: Amit Vaghela, I really appreciate your help, however these examples are regarding action-bar menu. Mines a little but different. I currently have 10 activities. One is the menu activities and the rest are the categories activities and I currently have created one fragment called menu fragment. How much more fragments will I need to create?.