# How to manage multiple Fragments with one single Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

a quick question about managing fragments.
Right now I am using this structure:

I have **one** `MainActivity` and multiple Fragments i.e. `LoginFragment`, `InventoryFragment`, `NetworkFragment` etc. I am using the `FragmentManager` for transcations and it works greatly so far.
But I have run into one issue. It is about handling the callbacks from the Fragments to the Activity.

I am using the simple way with interface callbacks which I define in the fragments and implement in the MainActivity, but as I get more and more Fragments it is getting really overcrowded with interfaces.

It looks for example like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoginFragmentCallback, InventoryFragmentCallback, NetworkFragmentCallback, AnyFragmentCallback
```

So my question is how can I manage the communication between Fragment and Activity better?

Thx for any help!

---

EDIT 1: I got an idea how to solve this with the comment from user @Rohit5k2

In my MainActivity I made a public method

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompat{
  public callMe();
}
```

In my Fragment I can call this method via

```
public class AnyFragment extends Fragment{
  private void someMethod(){
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).callMe();
}
```

Seems to solve the problem I think. Or is it bad? With this I dont need to implement any callback since I have a reference to the MainActivity with Fragments.

Comment: I think that is the best option you've got. It's better than holding on to references to your fragments inside your activity.

Comment: Why don't you implement the interface in fragments only? Implement only which is required.

Comment: Use local broadcasts. All fragments should broadcast events to the main activity. 
The main activity can update UI upon receiving events or decide what action to perform next.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager

Comment: Well, I guess this is a question with a lot of possible answers. I tend to keep my activities as slim as possible and nest related fragments instead. Talking to the parent fragment either using callback, or setTargetFrament

Comment: Regarding your edit, I would suggest that you ensure that the activity is instanceof MainActivity in the onAttatch method of your fragments. Or even better, have the activity implement a callback interface and check for that the same way. This way you are allowed to add other activities later on, while still enabling reuse of your fragments

Comment: @cYrixmorten Thanks for the tip. I was not planning to use more than one Activity. I think I will have to look into the pro's of using multiple Activities over Fragments to decide my further approach.

Comment: Check this link with detail description and examples http://stackoverflow.com/a/35013382/2826147

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to send data from the `Fragment` to the `Activity`, you can use `getActivity` and cast it to your main activity.

If you havr to go the other direction, maybe you are doing something wrong. A `Fragment` has to be independent enough from it's hosting activity.

Another suggestion is using an `Activity` for the login and after that start your main one.

For other kinds of communication, I recommend EventBus:
https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Seems like this is a valid solution. I am in the mindset of using one single Activity and split up the work into fragments. I will accept this later if there is no other suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I like the activity + lot of fragments myself, so I'm using this approach.

Activity implements interface

```
 interface ControllerAccess {
    <T> getController(Class<T> clazz);
 }
```

I have a `Map<Class,Object>` in activity. In `onCreate` i populate it with fragment specific controller class like yours `LoginFragmentCallback` etc.

```
map.put(LoginFragmentCallback.class,new LoginFragmentCallbackImpl());
```

and interface implementation looks like this

```
public <T> T getController(Class<T> clazz) {
   return (T) map.get(clazz);
 }
```

And in fragment i make something like

```
LoginFragmentCallback callback;

void onAttach(Activity activity) {

    if (activity instanceof ControllerAccess) {
        callback = (ControllerAccess)activity.getController(LoginFragmentCallback.class);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements FragmentInteractionListener {

 //your main activity code
}

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

//you can get resource from MainActivity using below code
(MainActivity) getActivity().getSomeInfo())

}
```